# ADODB error 800a0bb9; bit or integer?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I am currently trying to fire a stored procedure in classic ASP, but I have hit a snag with error 800a0bb9.

```
<%
Dim Command1__ChRef
Command1__ChRef = ""
if(Request("ChRef")  <> "") then Command1__ChRef = Request("ChRef") 

Dim Command1__ChLabelCheck
Command1__ChLabelCheck = ""
if(Request("ChLabelCheck")  <> "") then Command1__ChLabelCheck = Request("ChLabelCheck") 

Dim Command1__ChVehicleCheck
Command1__ChVehicleCheck = ""
if(Request("ChVehicleCheck")  <> "") then Command1__ChVehicleCheck = Request("ChVehicleCheck") 

Dim Command1__ChPaperworkCheck
Command1__ChPaperworkCheck = ""
if(Request("ChPaperworkCheck")  <> "") then Command1__ChPaperworkCheck = Request("ChPaperworkCheck") 

Dim Command1__ChLoadAccepted
Command1__ChLoadAccepted = ""
if(Request("ChLoadAccepted")  <> "") then Command1__ChLoadAccepted = Request("ChLoadAccepted") 

%>
<%
set Command1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Command1.ActiveConnection = MM_WebSalesSQL_STRING
Command1.CommandText = "dbo.ErgUpdateTechnicalReceiptChecks"
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", 3, 4)
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@ChRef", 3, 1,10,Command1__ChRef)
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@ChLabelCheck", 901, 1,10,Command1__ChLabelCheck)
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@ChVehicleCheck", 901, 1,10,Command1__ChVehicleCheck)
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@ChPaperworkCheck", 901, 1,10,Command1__ChPaperworkCheck)
Command1.Parameters.Append Command1.CreateParameter("@ChLoadAccepted", 901, 1,10,Command1__ChLoadAccepted)
Command1.CommandType = 4
Command1.CommandTimeout = 0
Command1.Prepared = true
Command1.Execute()
%>
```

The stored procedure calls for a bit. I have set it as a bit but the error states the type doesn't match? Should I pass it as an integer ("1") instead?  I get the feeling it is something as simple as this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the bits to integers, with the SQL database doing the rest.

Comment: Or you could just set it to the correct data type of `adBoolean` (11). When working out the correct data types in SQL Server *(if that is what you are using, you haven't specified)*, [this resource](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) has always helped me. Not even sure where you get 901 from, it's no [`DataTypeEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sql-server-2017) I've ever come across.

Comment: As I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 to code this, 901 was automatically generated when I set it to "bit". adBoolean and int seem to have worked either way. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it did seem like auto-generated template code. The best advice I can give you is... Burn Dreamweaver with fire!